# How to assing user to group using Dockerfile without shell?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

We have interesting problem using Dockerfile. We have base image which doesn't have shell (it was removed by security reason) and we can use only Dockerfile directives in our app Docker file. And also we want to run it in the non-root mode.

In the base image we have set of groups with different permissions. For example:

- g1 - group which has access to /var/log
- g2 - group which has access to /var/run/docker.sock

These groups are defined in the base image.

I want to have ability to run docker container using non-root user and assign my user to these two groups inside my app container which is based on the base image.

I found that USER directive we can specify user and group which will be used for running container (for example `USER app:g1`).

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# some code before
FROM base:1.0

USER app:g1

CMD ["./app"]
```

But I want to assign my user to two or more groups inside the Dockerfile of the app image.

**Notes** I can't modify base image, only the app image. And I have these groups on the host machine.

**Notes 2** `--group-add` flag for `docker run` is not an option for me, because container is started by some internal software, which I don't manage.

Can I do this? If yes - how?

I tried to specify group names in the `USER` directive via comma, but it doesn't work (I believe it shouldn't work because it's not documented, I just tried :)).

Comment: I think these are harming and really blocking constraints with no additional security. Can you use COPY in your dockerfile? `I want to have ability to run docker container using non-root user` I do not follow, inside the container you want to run docker containers, so docker-in-docker?

Comment: To run container in the non-root mode makes container a little bit safer if someone get access inside the container he/she can make less harm if container is running under non-root user. And access to `/var/run/docker.sock` is needed to get info about other docker containers which are running on the host. How COPY directive will help me in this case?

Comment: `get info about other docker containers which are running on the host` So you do not want to run docker-in-docker, but access the docker outside the container. So are teh groups `g1` and `g2` inside or outside the container? Do you know them by name or do you know them by gid? `How COPY directive will help me in this case?` You can `COPY` busybox and run shell inside. You can `COPY` prepared /etc/shadow and /etc/groups and change groups inside the container. Do you can use `RUN` from dockerfile? How is this policy enforced, do you use automated tools?

Comment: So, these groups `g1` and `g2` and user `app` are created on the host OS and inside the base image with same ids (group id and user id). I can't use RUN directive because there is no shell for my app Docker container.  I tried using `COPY` directive to override /etc/shadow and /etc/groups and it works for me like a charm, thanks a lot. Could be some issue with this approach (I mean overriding files) inside the Docker container? One disadvantage which I can see that somebody can easily corrupt /etc/group or /etc/passwd and it would be hard to find the issue.

Comment: `RUN directive because there is no shell for my app Docker` Yes, so you can `COPY busybox /bin` and then `RUN busybox any_command` and install busybox and have all the commands. Also, not having shell is not really an issue, anyway you can do  `RUN ["executable", "args"]` and execute `groupadd` or `usermod`. `Could be some issue` The issue is the lack of synchronization with base image. I do not understand the sentence with corrupting, it's as easy to corrupt as it was. Copy it with `COPY --chown=root:root` so it's owned by root.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense for me. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Those two directories look like things that you might expect to be bind-mounted from the host.  This means you can't specify the user or group IDs in the Dockerfile, since they'll vary depending on the specific host you're running on.

There is a [`docker run --group-add`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups) option that can assign additional groups to the main container process.  The linked example suggests the group IDs are looked up in the container's `/etc/groups` file so you might need to specify numeric group IDs.  The non-standard [**stat**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command can help you find these

```bash
docker run \
  -v "$PWD/logs:/var/log" \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --add-group $(stat -c %g /var/log) \
  --add-group $(stat -c %g /var/run/docker.sock) \
  ...
```

(On my local MacOS system, the BSD **stat**(1) takes a `-f` option rather than `-c`.)

Also consider that, if you have access to the host's Docker socket, you can all but trivially root the entire host (imagine running a new container as root that bind-mounts the host's `/etc/shadow` file to reset host-root's password, or `/etc/crontab` to run some command at the next minute boundary).  Consider `docker run -u 0` to run this container as root as well, which would bypass the other filesystem-permission considerations.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, you're right - it's mounted directories. But I have created users and groups with the same ids on the host and the inside the base image. The thing there that `--group-add` flag for `docker run` is not an option for me, because container is started by some internal software, which I don't manage. Is there any other options to assign multiple groups to user?

Comment: [Dockerfile `USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) only takes a single group ID, so I don't think there's a way to do this in the image.  You also can't guarantee that the specific numeric gids in the image will match the host where it's running, though it's possible to make them match up in individual cases.